# DevOps center error

Tags: devopscenter

I'm trying to do a large deployment into our UAT environment and the 'Stages' tab in DevOps Center won't load for me anymore. Each time I click on it i get the classic error message "There was an error.

[image]

Please reload the page or contact your system administrator if the problem persists."

It is nothing to do with storage limits, ive checked this and all orgs are less than 1% data storage used up.

I managed to deploy one small work item, but when I combined a few work items together for the next batch, I got a generic error and the deployment failed. Since then I have been unable to view the Stages tab. Did i combine too many work items?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it could be a known issue:

https://issues.salesforce.com/issue/a028c00000j5kNsAAI/getting-error-when-trying-to-connect-to-release-environment-via-devops-center